# Create custom date command using numbers

Tags: datetime, isodate

Is there any way to create a custom command that prints the date (using the language specified in `babel` to be possible) from a given ISO 8601-formatted date?

What I would like is that

```
\today
\customdate{160130} % or \customdate{20160130}
```

both print

[image]

Comment: `datetime2` has `\DTMdate` but it requires hyphens `\DTMdate{2016-01-30}`. Is that okay or does it have to be without separators?

Comment: I wouldn't mind. But `\DTMdate{2016-01-30}` just prints "2016-01-30".

Comment: Also, all the DTM styles specified in the documentation seem to be numerical.

Comment: The language modules are installed separately. The numeric style is the default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`datetime2`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2) package is designed to work with language packages, such as `babel` and `polyglossia`, but you need to additionally install the relevant language module. For example, [`datetime2-english`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-english) or [`datetime2-french`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-french). The numeric style is the default, but you can use the package option `useregional` to allow the language change to automatically change the date style.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,british]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{british}

\DTMdate{2016-01-30}.

\selectlanguage{french}

\DTMdate{2016-01-30}.

\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: 30th January 2016. 30 janvier 2016]

Edit:

The date styles are designed to be expandable so commands like `\today` can be used in contexts where information is written to an external file (such as table of contents or bookmarks). `\DTMdate` is robust which means it can't be expanded but it doesn't need protecting (with `\protect`). There's an expandable alternative `\DTMdisplaydate` but it has a different syntax, which doesn't fit your requirement. These differences can be illustrated with the following examples:

`\DTMdate`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,british]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\selectlanguage{british}

\section{\DTMdate{2016-01-30} example section}

\selectlanguage{french}

\section{\DTMdate{2016-01-30} example section}

\end{document}
```

The table of contents looks fine with this:

[image: image of table of contents]

The page header can't convert the date to upper case (because it's robust) and it's also using the wrong language:

[image: image of page 2]

The PDF bookmarks can't process robust commands, so the bookmarks use the numeric form given in the argument of `\DTMdate`:

[image: 2016-01-30 example section 2016-01-30 example section]

Now modifying the example to use `\today`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,british]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\selectlanguage{british}

\section{\today\ example section}

\selectlanguage{french}

\section{\today\ example section}

\end{document}
```

The contents page is the same as before, but the header on the next page is now correct (both language and case):

[image: image of page 2]

The PDF bookmarks are now fine:

[image: image of bookmarks]

The expandable version of `\DTMdate{2016-01-30}` is `\DTMdisplaydate{2016}{01}{30}{-1}` (or `\DTMdisplaydate{2016}{01}{30}{5}`) and will work in the same way as `\today`.

An alternative is to first store the date with `\DTMsavedate` and later use it with `\DTMusedate`, which is also expandable:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,british]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\DTMsavedate{mydate}{2016-01-30}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\selectlanguage{british}

\section{\DTMusedate{mydate} example section}

\selectlanguage{french}

\section{\DTMusedate{mydate} example section}

\end{document}
```

This produces the same as the earlier example with `\today`. The page headers and PDF bookmarks are correct.

Comment: Awesome, man! @egreg's answer is a bit more tedious and, alas, `isodate` does not support Catalan and Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

Using `isodate`, but feeding it the argument in the required format:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[english]{isodate}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \alfredo_date_printdate:n \printdate

\NewDocumentCommand{\customdate}{m}
 {
  \alfredo_date_customdate:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \alfredo_date_customdate:n
 {
  \int_case:nnF { \tl_count:n { #1 } }
   {
    { 6 } { \alfredo_date_customdate_short:n { #1 } }
    { 8 } { \alfredo_date_customdate_long:n { #1 } }
   }
   {BAD~DATE~FORMAT~(#1)}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \alfredo_date_customdate_short:n
 {
  \__alfredo_date_customdate:nnnnnnnn 20#1
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \alfredo_date_customdate_long:n
 {
  \__alfredo_date_customdate:nnnnnnnn #1
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__alfredo_date_customdate:nnnnnnnn
 {
  \alfredo_date_printdate:n { #1#2#3#4-#5#6-#7#8 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\today

\customdate{160130}

\customdate{20160130}

\customdate{16130}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason it seems to break the `\today` command when it's used in `\markboth{Derivations Sheet 1}{\today}` (it works just fine when used in any part of the document), but apart from that, it works as a charm.

Comment: @AlfredoHernández That's a fault of `isodate`: just use `\protect\today`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a custom version I built from scratch, although this would be reinventing the wheel since there are already packages dedicated to it.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring} % for extracting substrings
\usepackage[super]{nth} % for adding cardinal numbers
\usepackage{pgfmath} % for the array

\def\monthlist{{"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"}} 

\newcommand\printmonth[1]{%
    \pgfmathparse{\monthlist[\mmmm-1]}\pgfmathresult\
}

\newcommand\customdate[1]{%
    \StrMid{#1}{5}{6}[\dayx]
    \StrMid{#1}{3}{4}[\monthx]
    \pgfmathsetmacro\mmmm{int(abs(\monthx))}%
    \nth{\dayx}\ \printmonth \protected20\StrMid{#1}{1}{2}
}

\begin{document}  

\customdate{160130}

\customdate{110521}

\customdate{130702}

\customdate{161124}

\end{document}
```